# Visual Basic memory usage keeps expanding

Tags: vb.net, memory

Having a problem with the amount of memory being used going up and up, and expanding until there is no memory left. I'm using the `GHeat.Net` plugin to build images. Here is the full code:

```
Dim pm As New gheat.PointManager()
Dim g As Graphics

Dim startZoom As Integer = 2
Dim maxZoom As Integer = 17

gheat.Settings.BaseDirectory = "C:\\gheatWeb\\__\\etc\\"

pm.LoadPointsFromFile("C:\\points.txt")

For zoom As Integer = startZoom To maxZoom
    Dim startX As Integer = 0
    Dim startY As Integer = 0
    Dim maxX As Integer = 2 ^ zoom
    Dim maxY As Integer = 2 ^ zoom

    For x As Integer = startX To maxX
        For y As Integer = startY To maxY
            Dim filename As String = "C:\\images\\" + zoom.ToString + "\\x" + x.ToString + "y" + y.ToString + "zoom" + zoom.ToString + ".gif"
            gheat.GHeat.GetTile(pm, "classic", zoom, x, y).Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
        Next
    Next
Next
```

For some reason, when I hit the `for` loops, the amount of memory used just goes up and up and up, until it hits a ceiling. Even then, the program keeps running, but the amount of memory doesn't go up. The program generates fine at 20Mb, so I can't figure out why it just keeps going up.

I've also tried `GC.Collect` at the end of the innermost loop, to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GHeat.GetTile`](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=88956&zep=GHeat.Net%2fGHeat.cs&rzp=%2fKB%2fweb-image%2fGHeat_Net%2f%2fGHeat.Net.zip) returns a [`Bitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.aspx) which must be [disposed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx).
Also, there's no need to escape paths like that in VB.

```
For x As Integer = startX To maxX
  For y As Integer = startY To maxY
    Dim filename As String = String.Format("C:\images\{0}\x{1}y{2}zoom{3}.gif", zoom, x, y, zoom)
    Using img = gheat.GHeat.GetTile(pm, "classic", zoom, x, y)
      img.Save(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif)
    End Using
  Next
Next
```

Comment: This is great, it's not continually increasing the memory for each picture and never clearing. Awesome. Unfortunately, I'm still using up TONS of memory. Once zoom gets up to about 8 or 9, my memory usage hits nearly a gig a ram, and then doubles again on the next zoom level. I've tried memory profiling, but the only thing that goes up in that pattern is GC #1's. Argh. Any ideas?